# Joomla 1.7 first plugin event to be triggered

Tags: events, plugins, joomla, joomla1.7

What is the trigger order for Joomla 1.7 plugin events? I am looking for the first plugin event that is triggered when loading a Joomla 1.7 site.

A list of the events can be found here: 
http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin#Content

And a list of the renamed events for Joomla 1.7 can be found here: http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Renamed_events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, the first event triggered is "onAfterInitialise" ( a system event ).

Comment: Yes, that correct - I found a list of triggered plugin events by timeline here: http://softmarket.ro/joomla-tips/mambots-plugins-events-eventchart-all-available-triggers-for-joomla-mambo-and-joomla-1.5.html albeit it is a bit old. I tried using "onAfterInitialise" but this did not have access to JRequest vars so I ended up using "onAfterRoute".

Comment: Hi, I think you will be able to access request vars using "onAfterInitialise", but some of these vars will probably get overriden when after routing, so using "onAfterRoute" is better depending on what you have to do (i.e., if you have to access the option, task, view values or similar.